# Javascript onclick how to undo when clicked again

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, undo

I'm creating a filter to search for your perfect shoe's by answering questions. Right now I've got a couple of questions, each with multiple answers. By clicking on an answer a variable gets edited with the data of the value of that answer. The problemm is that you can click on the variable as many times as you like and the value will keep being added. Is there a way to change the color of the answer button when clicked and when clicked again it undo's adding the value to the variable and changes the color back?

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <div id="answer"></div>
    <button onclick="check()" id="nextbtn">Next</button>
    <div id="finalLink"></div>      
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ShoeTest = [
        [
            'Whats your size?',
            ['41', '41'],
            ['42', '42'],
            ['43', '43']
        ],
        [
            'What color would you like?',
            ['Red', 'red'],
            ['Blue', 'blue'],
            ['Yellow', 'yellow'],
            ['Green', 'green']
        ],
        [
            'What brand would you like?',
            ['Adidas', 'adidas'],
            ['Nike', 'nike'],
            ['Puma', 'puma']
        ]
    ];

    let parms = [];

    count = 1;
    var questionNumber = 0;
    var button = document.getElementById('answer');
    var question = document.getElementById('question');
    var answerButton;
    var flag = true;

    function getLink(parms) {
        return ""+parms.join("&")
      };

      button.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        const tgt = e.target;
        parms.push(tgt.value);
        console.log(getLink(parms))
      })

    function check(){
        oldAnswerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');
        oldQuestion = document.getElementById('question');
        for(let z = 0; z < oldAnswerButton.length; z++){
            oldAnswerButton[z].style.display = 'none';
        }
        //question 
        for (let y = 1; y < ShoeTest[questionNumber].length; y++){
            // button
            var btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.value = ShoeTest[questionNumber][y][1];
            btn.className = "filter_anwser";
            btn.textContent = ShoeTest[questionNumber][y][0];
            btn.setAttribute('data-el', 1);
            btn.onclick = ButtonColor();
            button.appendChild(btn);
            // class
            answerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');
        }
        // question
        question.textContent = ShoeTest[questionNumber][0];
        question.id = "questionID";
                
        console.log(".....");
        // adds 1 to question to see a different question
        questionNumber++;
    }

    function ButtonColor(){
        btn = document.getElementById('answer');
        btn.style.backgroundcolor = flag ? "unclicked" : "clicked"
       flag = !flag;
    }
```

Also if you have multiple answers of one questions add a , between instead of a &?

Comment: You're basically asking how to keep track of a switch being on or not. You can do this with a (boolean) variable, or by adding (and removing) a class to the button (this can also be used to apply different style rules, so would be a perfect solution here). If the search params are composed from all switch states you can simply re-run that each time a switch was toggled. Start simple and implement a basic toggle button, then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Here's the updated snippet based on the comments. Change your event listener function like below:

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (parms && parms.indexOf(tgt.value) == -1) {
    parms.push(tgt.value);
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    parms.splice(parms.indexOf(tgt.value), 1)
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  console.log(getLink(parms))
})
```

**PREVIOUSLY**

From your question, I can understand you are looking for changing the button color on click and click again (undo). And update the value that happens on click and click again (undo). Here's a more simplified example that exactly does this which you can apply in your problem:

```js
var flag = true;
function changeColorAndValue() {
    flag = !flag;
    document.getElementById("myButton").style.background = flag ? 'yellow' : 'blue';
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" onclick="changeColorAndValue()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Tnx but I've already tried doing something like that, but it doesn't work. maybe because the buttons are automatically generated in my function. And that changes the color but is there also a way to undo the entire function?

Comment: I have updated the answer. This switches color and undo the added value in second click. Hope you need this

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly. Just a question. Do you know a way to check if the clicked answer is from the same question as another clicked answer so I can add a , instead of an & between them?